# How to change the Default Shell Properties to Bash for non-local accounts that users Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, centos6, pam, rhel6

We did an integration of CentOS 6 with Active Directory. I would like to know how to change the Default Shell Properties to Bash for non-local accounts.

For the local accounts we use chsh -s /bin/bash [username]

So please help me here with the right options.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is going to entirely depend on how exactly you integrated the machine with AD. Did you use winbind, sssd, etc? And how did you configure that bridging tool. Some of them can be configured to read [RFC2307](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2307.txt) attributes directly from the AD user object. Some can be configured to just use the same value for all users specified in a config file on the local system. Others will still look in AD, but in a custom object not necessarily tied directly to the user.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Yes we are using winbind-samba configuration. winbind for authentication and samba for file sharing.  But now I need to set/change the default shell properties to bash for all those users in AD.

Comment: So are you using "rfc2307" mode or "template" mode? https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Idmap_config_ad